# UITableView inside UITableViewCell - didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am making an interface which have UITableView with four custom UITableViewCell's. And every other UITableViewCell have also UITableView. This mean I have TableView inside a TableView.

Let me call first tableView - ParentTableView and nested tableView - ChildTableView. So I implemented method didSelectRowAtIndexPath on both tableView's. But when the app is running, only the method of the ChildTableView is being called. I need to know inside the ParentTableView, which cell is being tapped.

How can I transfer that information further from ChildTableView to ParentTableView.

This may be a silly question, but I can not find any reliable solution so far, so please help me.

Thank You in advance, kind Sir

Comment: Why are you putting a table view inside the cell of another table view?

Comment: I am using inside table for simple scrollable graph view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I think nested table views is a bad idea. But I don't know your use case, so it might be an exception.

The table view controller class used inside a cell have its own `@protocol` definition and set the outer table view as its delegate. In the inner `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` it can inform the outer table view about the selected `indexPath`, its own `indexPath` and any other information you might want to transmit.

Comment: It's pretty obvious solution. Sometimes I am complicating things and forget how to do simple. Thanks for pointing it out. Accepted answer.

Comment: I am sorry for  asking question here  because it can't be posted as new question.(Community might close this)  Why Tableview inside tableview is bad idea ? . Actually I am implemented same. My use case is for order list. In order list cell there can be multiple order items so I have used tableview (Non scrollable ) inside cell for that order items . So what would be best option here ?.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Your use case is better served with a single flat table view. Either two kinds of table view cells, or work with sections and cells. But scroll view inside scroll view is always confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using collection views. You can do a layout that works like a regular table view and then in the cells that need to have a table, you can make those separate cells with another collection view inside or a table view inside of it.

As mentioned before, it's not easy doing table views inside of cells, and it can be very tricky to get things to work correctly.

[This is an old tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1) I wrote which may help and be of guidance. But since then there's been collection views and auto layout, so keep in mind it's very old.

Comment: Hi Felipe. At start I was using exactly this (Yours - thank you) tutorial. And then at some point I tweek the code a little bit. Yes, what I am doing can be a bit tricky, but for me, autolayout is sometimes even more complicated and requires a lot of work to. Thanks again

Comment: Just remember to try this (if you can) in the iOS 8 simulator and resizable simulators. It's pretty much a given that big-screen iPhones are coming, and you want your app to be ready, especially after working on something as custom as this.

Comment: I am pretty nervous already because of the different screen sizes. I have been an Android developer for 4 years and I got to tell you that android have this situation under control so easily...